# Strange delay behavior in Atmega328P

Tags: c, arduino, avr, arduino-uno, atmel

So, I have implemented a custom delay function using the standard one found at utils/delay.h.

```
inline void delay_us(uint16_t time) {
    while (time > 0) {
        _delay_us(1);
        time--;
    }
}
```

It's called inside a loop in the main function:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL

...

int main() {
    pin_mode(P2, OUTPUT);
    while (1) {
        pin_enable(P2);
        delay_us(1);
        pin_disable(P2);
        delay_us(1);
    }
}
```

Using an oscilloscope, I can tell that the pin stays 1.120us high and 1.120us low, with 1 as parameter. Incrementing the parameter to 6, the the oscilloscope shows me 6.120us. But with 7, it stays 9 us. With 10, about 14 us. 

I know the loop comes with an overhead, but why there is no overhead (or why the overhead does not changes) between 1 and 6 us?

**OBS:** I'm using an Arduino UNO (16 MHz)

Comment: Probably it is unrolling the loop for small values of `time`. Try using a variable as a parameter rather than a constant.

Comment: 1 us is 16 CPU clock cycles. So, actually, all the delay you have is overhead rather than "_dethe lay...". Since you made function "inline", the compiler just replaces its call (assuming the parameter is a constant) with an inlined loop. So it is mostly depended on how compiler will optimize that loop (e.g. unroll it, etc)

Comment: @EugeneSh. the delay function just allow an integer constant as parameter.

Comment: Is there a proper way to implement a delay with micro precision without doing assembly code?

Comment: Best way for a delay function is to use timer. Always remember the optimiziation of your compiler.

Comment: I agree that doing this with a timer is the way to go. But if that is not possible and the quality of the output signal relies strongly on how many cycles are used for an operation, I would suggest to do it in assembly instead of compiled code.

Comment: @HugoSartori `delay_us(x)` where `x is a variable you, say, read from user or calculate in runtime. In this scenario the compiler won't know how long the loop is and will not unroll it.

Comment: I guess I'll need to spend some time analysing the generated assembly for different scenarios.

Comment: @StefanBormann I thought about that, but I'm developing a small library to use PWM, so I'm trying to not cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Yea, that jitter is unexpected. You can totally avoid that by using the timer hardware of the controller - that's easy for PWM.

Comment: If clock frequency doesn't change you could also fine tune using `_NOP()` from `avr/cpufunc.h`. Not very flexible, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For small arguments gcc-avr will unroll the while loop, effectively stringing together multiple 1µs-delays:

```
delay_us(5):
    ldi r24,lo8(5)
    mov r25,r24
    1: dec r25
    brne 1b
    mov r25,r24
    1: dec r25
    brne 1b
    mov r25,r24
    1: dec r25
    brne 1b
    mov r25,r24
    1: dec r25
    brne 1b
    1: dec r24
    brne 1b
```

At some point however, the compiler changes its strategy from space-consuming unrolling to actually branching through the while loop:

```
delay_us(6):
    ldi r24,lo8(6)
    ldi r25,hi8(6)
    ldi r19,lo8(5)
.L2:
    mov r18,r19
    1: dec r18
    brne 1b
    sbiw r24,1
    brne .L2
```

At that time, the carefully crafted `_delay_us()` function will be more or less defeated. The branch overhead is significant compared to the 16 clock cycles needed for a single `_delay_us(1)` and will be paid for every loop iteration.

The sudden increase in runtime you describe is basically the point at which your compiler stops to unroll the loop.

Compare this to calling `_delay_us(6)` directly:

```
_delay_us(6):
    ldi r24,lo8(32)
    1: dec r24
    brne 1b
```

The assembly shown above might differ somewhat from what your compiler is doing since compiler output can vary significantly with version and flags but the listings should be reasonably close.
For the examples I assumed gcc-avr 4.6.4 with optimization level `-O2`. 
[Try it out](https://godbolt.org/z/aOevfk)